# Simple Python Function with an if statement not working?

Tags: python-3.x, function

Why is the function defined as shown below not working? I am getting the error msg
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Thanks in advance.

```
import math
from math import sin, cos, exp, pi, sqrt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def pulse(Amax,td,t):
    if t<=td:
        y = Amax*sin((pi/td)*t)
    else:
        y = 0
    return y

t = np.linspace(0,4*pi,100)
Amax=10
td=11/1000
plt.plot(t,pulse(Amax,td,t), 'r', label='pulse A=10,td=11')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 2):

In `t <= td` you are directly comparing a scalar with an array. That type of operation is ambiguous because it can't determine what a truth value should be.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the "standard" python way of defining such simple function?

Comment: That's actually from numpy, which is not standard Python. Check their docs.

Answer (score 0):

ugly but works

```
i=0
y=zeros(N0); ti=zeros(N0)

for t in np.arange(0,tend,dt):
    ti[i]=t
    if t <= td:
        y[i]=amax*np.sin(wf*t)
    else:
        y[i]=0
    i+=1
```

## ------------

Maybe a slightly better code

```
trg = np.arange(0,tend,dt)   # start,stop,step
for i,t in enumerate(trg):
    if t <= td:
        y[i]=amax*np.sin(wf*t)
    else:
        y[i]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In plt.plot you give 2 arrays. its better to create array y beforehand using iterating over array t with suitable conditions or your function pulse should return an array.
like

```
def pulse (Amax,td,t):
    y=[]
    for i in t:
        if i <= td:
            y.append(Amax*sin((pi/td)*i))
        else:
            y.append(0)
    return y
```

at last just use 
`plt.plot(t,pulse(Amax,td,t), whatever you want here)`